# How to programatically digitally sign an open office XML Docx document with X509 Certificate?

Tags: digital-signature, x509certificate

I want to programatically digitally sign an open office XML Docx document with X509 Certificate either in Java or C#.

This link does it brilliantly with C# using PackageDigitalSignatureManager from System.IO.Packaging:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/wouterv/archive/2007/02/24/Signing-Office-Open-XML-documents-using-the-Packaging-API.aspx

Altough this works fine, at the end it prompts a user dialog to ask him for a PIN Number for the authenticated digital signature.

Do you know how to set this PIN Number programatically?

Cheers

---

Thank you for the detailed answer. 
Basically, I'm using an electronic ID smartcard, which has a certificate for signing digital documents.

Typically I pass a public key in X509Certificate type, to PackageDigitalSignatureManager  Sign() method.

This method will sign the document, but will prompt the user for a PIN in order to retrieve the Private key stored in the smart card.

Isn't it possible to pass the PackageDigitalSignatureManager an Object which includes both the Public/Private key pair in a PKCS12 file, and then it won't prompt the user for a PIN number.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question #2 depends on what technology you use and, more importantly, where the certificate is stored.

In Java Key Storage (JKS) certificates are protected with passwords and those passwords are passed in code.

In Windows Certificate Storage (location that .NET cryptography classes use) certificates are protected using PIN which can not be set by code for most cryptoproviders (there's extension command to set the PIN but most providers don't support it) and the user needs to confirm access to the private key by hand.

If you use certificate stored in PKCS12 file, then the password for the file is also set in code.

And, well, we offer components for signing office documents in .NET, if you are interested ([check here](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-office.php)). They are maintained and supported, unlike most sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa905326.aspx) That covers it. 
3 steps necessary