# How to digitally sign Open Office XML document in client-server paradigm with ASP .NET webservices?

Tags: .net, digital-signature, x509certificate, smartcard, digital-certificate

I want to create a web application that can access a smart card with a digital certificate, and then digitally sign an open office XML document on the server. I know a couple of open source frameworks that do this in Java, but the client requires me to do it in .NET C#:

The SignServer Dot Org

The belgian eID Applet

Anyone has some guidelines or recommendations how to implement this .NET C#?

Has the PackageDigitalSignatureManager from System.IO.Packaging has some use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use system.io.packaging (see the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336848/how-to-programatically-digitally-sign-an-open-office-xml-docx-document-with-x509) about this) and you can use our [OfficeBlackbox components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-office.php).